# My log is filled with updatePointerIcon called with position out of bounds

Tags: android

i like to keep my log clean, but thanks to a button, my log fills up with lots of

```
"updatePointerIcon called with position out of bounds"
```

messages
the app works as it should, the onClick is called when i click on the button, so everything seems nice and working, only those annoying messages clog my log and i don't know what they mean.... and how to get rid of them...

the button is instantiated inside of a TableView in this fashion:

```
  TableRow.LayoutParams llp = new  TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  llp.setMargins(0, 0, 2, 0);//2px right-margin
  Button tv = new Button(context);
  tv.setText("token");//TODO internationalize
  tv.setPadding(0, 0, 4, 3);
  tv.setOnClickListener(this);
  tv.setHint("token");
  newRow.addView(tv);
```

nothing fancy, really.... quite mysterious, and since i don't know what going wrong where and everything works as it should, i have trouble deciding what code should be published to illustrate this, so if someone could shed some light on this?
thanks!

follow up:
  in the onClick:

```
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
 DialogFragAddToken editNameDialog = new DialogFragAddToken();
 editNameDialog.setAddTokenDialogListener(this);
 editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_add_token");
```

and the DialogFragAddToken is of

```
 public class DialogFragAddToken  extends DialogFragment implements OnEditorActionListener
```

Comment: Does the message show up after you press the button?
What does the button do when clicked?

Comment: it opens a dialogfragment, i edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be generated by ViewRootImpl when a dialog-sized view is focused and the pointer (mouse in my case) is outside the view's occupied area. They appear to be harmless.